# Eclipse: can not change file association

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse: tried to use Text editor for .xml and .properties by changing the file associations

```
Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Editor -> File assocations
```

Can not remove or change order of the associated apps.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that `*.xml` files are opened with the XML Editor is due to the content types settings: ***Window > Preferences: General > Content Types*** (*Text > XML*). Also for `*.properties` files there is an associated editor in *Content Types* (*Text > Java Properties File*).

If you want to open by default `*.xml` and  `*.properties` files with the text editor, do the following in ***Window > Preferences: General > Content Types***:

1. Click ***Add Root...*** and enter a name, e. g. `XML`
2. Kepp the new content type selected and in the section ***File associations*** click ***Add...*** and enter **`*.xml`**
3. Kepp the new file association selected and in the section ***Associated editors*** click ***Add...*** and choose the ***Text Editor***

Repeat the steps with for `*.properties` files.

Comment: Eclipse 2019-09: I want to auto associate *.xml, *.xsl, and *.xsd with XMLspy. I've tried the above but unfortunately it isn't working. The problem is I think that there is already an automatic Eclipse "ant build" content-based association for these file extensions. Eclipse for reasons of it's own prevents me from removing these and even though I have added my own as you explain above, it gives its internal associations priority (I have tried restarting Eclipse post adding my own and still no joy)

Comment: @Pancho Will these files still be opened with the wrong editor when right-clicking a file and choosing _Open With > Default Editor_?

Comment: I've removed the config, but I need double click and have XMLspy open the file by default. I can currently achieve this using file association rather than content association. The problem is there are behavioural differences doing this than my preferred method of "having no Eclipse default" and setting the preference "Open unassociated files with: System Editor; if none: Text Editor" ...but as I can't "delete" these pre-defined content-associations for .xsl,.xml and .xsd I can't use that method.

Comment: Doesn't work for Eclipse  Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0)

Comment: @timmacp Could you verify that in the preferences _General > Editors > File Associations_ adding a file type for `*.xml` or for `*.properties` works instead?

Comment: File types contained loads of obscure ones, but not .XML (I added it). I set File association to generic text editor but it doesn't work. Maybe I should revert to my 2021 eclipse version

Comment: @timmacp It works for me in 2023-12 and the _Generic Text Editor_ is the default editor for `*.xml` files. What content types and file associations do you have for `*.xml`? Which IDE package do you have and did you install additional plugins? When you right click a file and choose _Open With > Other..._ there is the option _Use it for all '*.xml’ files_.

Comment: I was just looking at pom.xml files : turns out there's a special file association for those, which I deleted so now its ok. I haven't seen the "Use it for all..." option recentl: I guess that only appears if there is no file association set. Its Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers

Answer (score 0):

Under file types remove .xml and .properties, add them again, the click on each one and in the view below select the editor you want to be associated with the file type selected. if multiple you can select one as the default. Should be pretty straight forward.